# 2 IP addresses entering my house from the same fiber optic line: What piece of equipment do I need to separate into two physical lines?

Tags: networking

My ISP (providing fiber optic service) has told me that they will be able to provide 2 static IP addresses through the single fiber optic line to the house.  A standard RJ45 (I believe that's what it is) ethernet cable enters the house that will, presumably, carry both of these IP addresses.

I would like to separate the two IP addresses that are present on this single physical cable into two separate cables, one carrying each IP address.

What piece of equipment do I need to purchase to do this (specifically)?  I gather this is a switch or gateway of some sort, but I do not know *exactly* what identifies this piece of equipment.

Comment: What's up with the downvote?  Give me a break.

Answer (score 2):

IP addresses are bound to interfaces, not lines. You can use a normal switch that you can pick up anywhere for cheap, have two machines/devices plugged into it, and have the external interface on the devices assigned to the two addresses.

Comment: Thanks!  What is the "switch" that I need to pick up?  That is my question... what do I search for on NewEgg, or Amazon, for example?

Comment: Just... "switch". Something that plugs into the other end of your modem, which provides Ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a simple modem and a switch. The modem will pass both of the addresses through to your network with few complaints. Things get a little trickier if you have a router in the mix as most consumer grade routers have a single WAN interface supporting only one address.

Ideally what you need is either two routers to handle each address (sloppy) or a router capable of multiple assignments on the same interface. DD-WRT has this capability as do many other Linux based routers.